# using ng-options for an object within an array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this array of objects here:

```
$scope.breadsticks = [
  {
    name: 'Garlic Buttered',
    price: { priceSM: 3.99, priceMD: 4.99, priceLG: 5.99 },
    size: { sizeSM: '6 pcs', sizeMD: '10 pcs', priceLG: '14 pcs' },
    description: 'Garlic buttery goodness on a stick of cheesy bread.',
  },
  {
    name: 'Mozzarella Stuffed',
    price: { priceSM: 4.49, priceMD: 5.49, priceLG: 6.49 },
    size: { sizeSM: '6 pcs', sizeMD: '10 pcs', priceLG: '14 pcs' },
    description: 'Jam packed with that mozzarella gucci we know you love.',
  }
];
```

I want to create a select list that only displays the `size: { sizeSM: '6 pcs', sizeMD: '10 pcs', priceLG: '14 pcs' }` information:

```
<td>
  <select ng-model="breadstick.selectedItem" ng-options="breadstick.size for breadstick in breadsticks">
  </select>
</td>

<td>
  {{breadstick.selectedItem.price}}
</td>
```

And I would also like the corresponding price to be displayed when the select list changes.

Any help or bumps into the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

[Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/vn2ppwp9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ngRepeat` object syntax:

```
<td>
    <select ng-model="breadstick.selectedItem" ng-options="size as text for (size, text) in breadstick.size">
    </select>
</td>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/vn2ppwp9/1/

Edit: If you want to get the price for the selected item size, it'd be easier to reformat the data like so:

```
$scope.breadsticks = [
{
  name: 'Garlic Buttered',
  price: [
      {
          size: "small",
          price: 3.99
      }, {
          size: "medium",
          price: 4.99
      }, {
          size: "large",
          price: 5.99 
      }
  ],
  size: [{
      size: "small",
      text: '6 pcs'
  }, {
      size: "medium",
      text: '10 pcs', 
  }, {
      size: "large",   
      text: '14 pcs' 
  }],
  description: 'Garlic buttery goodness on a stick of cheesy bread.',
},
{
  name: 'Mozzarella Stuffed',
  price: [
      {
          size: "small",
          price: 4.49
      }, {
          size: "medium",
          price: 5.49
      }, {
          size: "large",
          price: 6.49 
      }
  ],
  size: [{
      size: "small",
      text: '6 pcs'
  }, {
      size: "medium",
      text: '10 pcs', 
  }, {
      size: "large",   
      text: '14 pcs' 
  }],
  description: 'Jam packed with that mozzarella gucci we know you love.',
}
];
```

Now you can update the view repeat as:

```
<select ng-change="getPrice(breadstick, breadstick.selectedItem.size)" ng-model="breadstick.selectedItem.size" ng-options="size.size as size.text for size in breadstick.size">
</select>
```

Where the `getPrice` function:

```
$scope.getPrice = function(breadstick, size) {
    for (var i = 0; i < breadstick.price.length; i++) {
        if (breadstick.price[i].size == size) {
            breadstick.selectedItem.price =  breadstick.price[i].price;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, this works for displaying the select list. Do you know how I can determine the corresponding price depending on which item is selected?

Comment: @AlexDiVito -- Yeah... are you allowed to change properties of the `size` attribute? Or does the data have to be formatted like so?

Comment: we can do whatever works. I was just trying to keep everything bunched in this breadsticks array so that it can be reused in the ng-repeat directive.. but i'm open to anything

Comment: Alright, give me a min, going to give it a slight refactor.

Comment: @AlexDiVito -- Here's a fiddle getting the price - I'll update the answer: https://jsfiddle.net/vn2ppwp9/2/

Comment: well done!! thanks a bunch, ever since I decided to allow for different size Orders.. I have been needing to refactor my data and I wasn't sure how exactly.

Comment: @AlexDiVito -- You could also attach the price directly under the `size` property to avoid a lookup

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81097/discussion-between-alex-di-vito-and-tymejv).

Answer (score 0):

Use **json** filter:

```
<select ng-model="breadstick.selectedItem" ng-options="breadstick.size as (breadstick.size | json) for breadstick in breadsticks">
</select>
```